# Search filter using EditText from SQLite ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

My `ListView` is correctly doing its fetching from SQLite database, but my problem is that I have added `EditText` to filter by name. So if I enter any letter in my `EditText`, it should filter accordingly, but its not happening. Below is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<StudentEntity> listentity = new ArrayList<StudentEntity>();
    String texto="";
    texto=inputSearch.getText().toString();

     String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.naman.namrathasrinivas.choultriesbangalore" + "/databases/";
     String DB_NAME = "Marriage.sqlite";
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM hall WHERE name LIKE '%\" + texto + \"%' ";
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StudentEntity sentity = new StudentEntity();
            sentity.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            sentity.setLocality(cursor.getString(12));
            listentity.add(sentity);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing log of the query?? What is exactly happening??

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is wrong

```
"SELECT * FROM hall WHERE name LIKE '%\" + texto + \"%' ";
```

here `textto` is getting treated as string itself.

Try the query as following :

```
"SELECT * FROM hall WHERE name LIKE '%" + texto + "%'";
```

Here "textTo"'s value will get concatenated in the actual SQL query not the "textTo" itself.